# How do I find the ratio of $T_n$ to $S_n$ in this case?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> If $S_n=\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n}\frac {1}{\binom{n}{r}}} $ and $T_n=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n}\frac {r}{\binom{n}{r}}$ then what is $\displaystyle{\frac {T_n}{S_n}} $ in terms of $n$?

I tried the usual tricks I know from Binomial Theorem and Series but to no avail.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Did you try to compute for small values of $n$ ?

Comment: Related for S: https://oeis.org/A046825, and https://oeis.org/A046826. Neither numerator nor denominator of T are listed in OEIS.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze It is not listed because there is a simple rule form $T_n$ to $S_n$

Comment: The first few values of the quotient $\frac{T_n}{S_n}$ have a simple pattern: $\left\{\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{5}{2},3,\frac{7}{2},4,\frac{9}{2},5,\frac{11}{2},6,\frac{13}{2},7,\frac{15}{2},8,\frac{17}{2},9,\frac{19}{2},10\right\}$

Comment: Generalization: to my surprise the same result holds for the quotient for any real power $\alpha$ of the binomial coeffient: $\sum _{r=0}^n \frac{r}{\binom{n}{r}^{\alpha }}/\sum _{r=0}^n \frac{1}{\binom{n}{r}^{\alpha }}=\frac{n}{2}$ Try for instance $\alpha = 2, -1, \frac{1}{2}, \pi$

Answer (score 4):

Use the symmetry of the binomial coefficients: $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$. Then
$$\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{r}{\binom{n}{r}}=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{n-r}{\binom{n}{n-r}}=\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{n-r}{\binom{n}{r}}=n\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{1}{\binom{n}{r}}-\sum_{r=0}^n \frac{r}{\binom{n}{r}}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Okay...umm then what? A lil more hints please :) I'm not too good with series, I know basics only, are you referring to some formula?

Comment: No formula is needed here. The left-hand side is $T_n$. What is the right-hand side?

Comment: I get $\frac{T_n$}{S_n} = \frac{n}{2} $ holy moly thanks a lot, that was sooo obvious!!!!

Comment: May be, you could propose this new sequence to OEIS (joke). Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the ratio is simple even if there is no closed formula for both $T_n$ and $S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment showing (a) that closed expressions for $S$ and $T$ separately do exist, and (b) extends the relation to arbitrary functions of the binomial coefficient.

*(a) closed expressions*

These are not mentioned explicitly in OEIS. We designate them as $s_{c}$ and $t_{c}$, respectively.

Mathematica gives

$$\sum _{r=0}^n r! (n-r)! =  2^{-n-1} \Gamma (n+2) (-i\pi - B_2(n+2,0)) \tag{1}$$

where $B_z(a,b)$ is the incomplete Beta function (see e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).

Hence follows

$$s_{c}(n) = 2^{-n-1} (n+1) (-B_2(n+2,0)-i \pi )$$

and, with the result $n/2$ for the quotient,

$$t_{c}(n) =\frac{n}{2}  2^{-n-1} (n+1) (-B_2(n+2,0)-i \pi )$$

The appearance of the imaginary term $-i \pi$ can be understood from the defining integral representation

$$B_z(a,b)= \int_0^z u^{a-1} (1-u)^{b-1} \, du\tag{2}$$

I find that there is simpler integral formula for $S$ where the singularity at $u= 1$ has to be treated with the principal value:

$$s_{cp}(n) = 2^{-n-1} (n+1) \;P\int_0^2 \frac{u^{n+1}}{u-1} \, du\tag{3}$$

*(b) genralization to arbitrary functions*

Due to the basic relation of the binomial coefficients

$$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$$

we have for any function f(x)

$$\sum _{r=0}^n r f(\binom{n}{r})=\sum _{r=0}^n (n-r) f(\binom{n}{n-r})=\sum _{r=0}^n (n-r) f(\binom{n}{r})=n \sum _{r=0}^n  f(\binom{n}{r})-\sum _{r=0}^n  f(\binom{n}{r}) $$

and it follows that

$$n/2 = \sum _{r=0}^n r f(\binom{n}{r})/\sum _{r=0}^n f(\binom{n}{r})\tag{4}$$